# Quantstrat applyStrategy failure

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am using quantstart but for some reason the applyStrategy function does not spit out any information. It just goes through. As a result, when I then do the `tradeStats` function I get null. Here is the code I used: Thanks!

```
library(quantstrat)
library(quantmod)
initDate = "1999-01-01"
from = "2003-01-01"
to = "2015-12-31"

Sys.setenv (TZ = "UTC")
currency ("USD")
getSymbols ("SPY", from = from,
 to = to, src = "yahoo",
 adjust = TRUE)

tradesize <- 100000
initeq <- 100000
strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "firststrat"
rm.strat(strategy.st)
initPortf(portfolio.st,
 symbols = "SPY",
 initDate = initdate,
 currency = "USD")
initAcct(account.st,
 portfolios = portfolio.st,
 initDate = initdate,
 currency = "USD",
 initEq = initeq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate = initdate)
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
 name = "SMA",
 arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n = 200),
 label = "SMA200")

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
 name = "SMA",
 arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n = 50),
 label = "SMA50")

test4 <- applyIndicators(strategy = strategy.st, mktdata) 

add.signal(strategy.st,
 name = "sigCrossover",
 arguments = list(columns = c("SMA50", "SMA200"),
 relationship = "gt"),
 label = "longfilter")

add.signal(strategy.st,
 name = "sigComparison",
 arguments = list(columns = c("SMA50", "SMA200"),
 relationship = "lt" ),
 label = "filterexit")

test4 <- applySignals(strategy.st, mktdata)

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
 arguments = list(sigcol = "filterexit", sigval = TRUE,
 orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
 orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
 prefer = "Open"),
 type = "exit")

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
 arguments = list(sigcol = "longfilter", sigval = TRUE,
 orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
 orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
 prefer = "Open"),
 type = "enter")



applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolio.st)

updatePortf(portfolio.st)
daterange <- time(getPortfolio(portfolio.st)$summary)[-1]

updateAcct(account.st, daterange)
updateEndEq(account.st)

tradeStats(Portfolios = portfolio.st)
```

```

Answer (score 3):

Here were your issues:

1) Your `initDate` should be `initdate` on line 3 to be consistent.
2) Don't use`orderqty = "all"` for "enter" type rules.  Use an actual quantity.  See the entry add rule below.  below for how you probably intended the code to run. As a general rule, use `orderqty = "all"` for exit/stop/take profit type rules.  "all" is for when you want to get out of an existing position, without specifying what that position might be at the time (you may not know in advance if you're pyramiding trades into desired exposures)

3) You may encounter another bug related to `date` and `POSIXct` object comparisons if you don't set the `index.class` argument as below in the call to `getSymbols`

4) You didn't define the instrument object for `SPY`.  i.e. your code you posted is missing `stock("SPY", currency = "USD")`

5) Your code isn't reproducible as is. Calls like this:

```
test4 <- applyIndicators(strategy = strategy.st, mktdata)
```

only work after you've got marketdata object (which exists after a call to `applyStrategy`).

This edited form of your code works:

```
library(quantstrat)
library(quantmod)
initdate = "1999-01-01"
from = "2003-01-01"
to = "2015-12-31"

currency ("USD")
stock("SPY", currency = "USD")

Sys.setenv (TZ = "UTC")

getSymbols ("SPY", from = from,
            to = to, src = "yahoo",
            adjust = TRUE,
            index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"))

tradesize <- 100000
initeq <- 100000
strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "firststrat"
rm.strat(strategy.st)
initPortf(portfolio.st,
          symbols = "SPY",
          initDate = initdate,
          currency = "USD")
initAcct(account.st,
         portfolios = portfolio.st,
         initDate = initdate,
         currency = "USD",
         initEq = initeq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate = initdate)
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n = 200),
              label = "SMA200")

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n = 50),
              label = "SMA50")

add.signal(strategy.st,
           name = "sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("SMA50", "SMA200"),
                            relationship = "gt"),
           label = "longfilter")

add.signal(strategy.st,
           name = "sigComparison",
           arguments = list(columns = c("SMA50", "SMA200"),
                            relationship = "lt" ),
           label = "filterexit")

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "filterexit", sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open"),
         type = "exit")

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "longfilter", sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = tradesize, ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open"),
         type = "enter")



applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolio.st)

updatePortf(portfolio.st)
daterange <- time(getPortfolio(portfolio.st)$summary)[-1]

updateAcct(account.st, daterange)
updateEndEq(account.st)

tradeStats(Portfolios = portfolio.st)
```

A final tip.  Restart a clean r session before running code which you want to be reproducible, then check it by running source.  Many of the issues I've listed above you could spot by running your source code in a new clean R session.  (If you use Rstudio this is easily done by using the short cut ctrl + shift + f10).

Comment: Thank you. This is the best example with entry - exit rules that actually works. Most examples that I have see, have, for example, 1 entry and 2 or 3 exit that is not logical. One question for your code is that when I rerun applyStrategy I get Error in addTxn(Portfolio = portfolio, Symbol = symbol, TxnDate = txntime,  : 
  Transactions must be added in order. TxnDate (2004-10-28) is before last transaction in portfolio (2015-12-10) for SPY . Is that correct? The manual is limited. Thank you